# How can I change baselines code output/replay (PPO) on github?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to run my own version of baselines code source of reinforcement learning on github: (https://github.com/openai/baselines/tree/master/baselines/ppo2).

Whatever I do, I keep having the same display which looks like this :

[image]

Where can I edit it ?  I know I should edit the "learn" method but I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those prints are the result of the following block of code, which can be found at [this link](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/ppo2/ppo2.py#L223) (for the latest revision at the time of writing this at least):

```
if update % log_interval == 0 or update == 1:
    ev = explained_variance(values, returns)
    logger.logkv("serial_timesteps", update*nsteps)
    logger.logkv("nupdates", update)
    logger.logkv("total_timesteps", update*nbatch)
    logger.logkv("fps", fps)
    logger.logkv("explained_variance", float(ev))
    logger.logkv('eprewmean', safemean([epinfo['r'] for epinfo in epinfobuf]))
    logger.logkv('eplenmean', safemean([epinfo['l'] for epinfo in epinfobuf]))
    logger.logkv('time_elapsed', tnow - tfirststart)
    for (lossval, lossname) in zip(lossvals, model.loss_names):
        logger.logkv(lossname, lossval)
    logger.dumpkvs()
```

If your goal is to still print some things here, but different things (or the same things in a different format) your only option really is to modify this source file (or copy the code you need into a new file and apply your changes there, if allowed by the code's license).

If your goal is just to suppress these messages, the easiest way to do so would probably be by running the following code before running this `learn()` function:

```
from baselines import logger
logger.set_level(logger.DISABLED)
```

That's using [this function](https://github.com/openai/baselines/blob/master/baselines/logger.py#L244) to disable the baselines logger. It might also disable other `baselines`-related output though.